# Understanding Node.js Stream API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use Node.js Stream API with the [node-serialport](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) module. The device I am trying to communicate with has its own protocol I need to implement.

I have created two Transform classes.

```
const Delimiter = class Delimiter extends Transform {

    constructor() {
        super({})

        this.delimiter = new Buffer(Token.TERMINATOR)
        this.buffer = new Buffer(0)
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        let data = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, chunk])

        let index

        while ((index = data.indexOf(this.delimiter)) !== -1) {
            this.push(data.slice(0, index + 1))
            data = data.slice(index + this.delimiter.length)
        }

        this.buffer = data
        callback()
    }

}

const Decoder = class Decoder extends Transform {

    constructor(protocol, entity) {
        super({objectMode: true})

        this.protocol = protocol
        this.entity = entity
    }

    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const decoded = decode(this.protocol, this.entity, chunk)
        this.push(decoded)
        callback()
    }
}
```

Which I can elegantly chain like following:

```
serialPort.pipe(new Delimiter()).pipe(new Decoder(Protocol, Entity.CLIENT))
```

What I would really like to do, is use this very elegant and efficient solution that pipes provide with the SerialPort's `write` method.

Is there any way this can be done? Is it possible to somehow add `Transform` objects to the `write` method so that whenever I call something like `serialPort.write(new DeviceInfoRequest())` the object gets passed to the pipeline and gets processed?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then simply inversing the command would work.

So it would work like this:

`const stream = new Delimiter().pipe(new Decoder(Protocol, Entity.CLIENT)).pipe(serialPort)`

And then instead of calling write on the serialPort object you would call on the `stream` obeject.